# OSX - make cursor click at particular screen coordinates

Tags: objective-c, ruby, macos

On a mac running OS X (mavericks), how can I make a cursor click at particular coordinates on my screen X times per second?

I'm assuming something like this must be possible from command line, but I haven't been able to find any relevant functions / libraries. I'm assuming they would be in Objective-c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating synthesised click events can be done via [Quartz Event Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html).

To simulate a click at location (100.0/100.0) you can use the following code:

```
CGPoint location = CGPointMake(100.0, 100.0);
CGEventRef theEvent = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown, location, kCGMouseButtonLeft);
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(theEvent, kCGMouseEventClickState, 1);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
CGEventSetType(theEvent, kCGEventLeftMouseUp);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, theEvent);
CFRelease(theEvent);
```

Please note that you might run into problems when trying to use Event Service APIs in combination with Sandboxing.